# XPages NoAccessSignal exception

Tags: jquery-mobile, xpages

A customer has a number of XPages applications that have a jQuery Mobile user interface for use on iPads. They have been working fine for a long time. There have been no application code changes, but recently users are reporting strange behaviour in the user interface across a number of the applications.

This seems to be related to multi-value fields where JQM shows a long list of values in an overlay. When then selecting a second multi-value field the pop-up box is being displayed but then immediately replaced with the overlay for the first field but without any values.

The Domino server is 8.5.3 FP4 and the administrators tell me there have been no environment and security changes recently.

In addition to the above I am also seeing the following errors occurring :-

```
16/12/15 15:54: Exception Thrown
com.ibm.xsp.acl.NoAccessSignal
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext.checkAccess(NotesContext.java:1631)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext.serverProcessSignedResource(NotesContext.java:975)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext.setSignerSessionRights(NotesContext.java:946)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader$DynamicClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:171)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.Application.loadClass(Application.java:708)
    at com.ibm.xsp.library.ApplicationFacesClassLoader.loadClass(ApplicationFacesClassLoader.java:54)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledPageDriver.getClassForPageName(CompiledPageDriver.java:169)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledPageDriver.loadPage(CompiledPageDriver.java:61)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:489)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:557)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doCreateView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:141)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerEx.createView(ViewHandlerEx.java:90)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:238)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:204)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:583)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1281)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:860)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:803)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:572)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1265)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:658)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:481)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:341)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:297)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
```

There doesn't seem to be any indication as to which application or XPage these exceptions are related to. And I do not know whether this is related to the issues being seen in the user interface of the various applications.

Can anyone shed any light on this exception or what I should be looking for?

Comment: Could the strange behaviour be caused by upgrades to iOS 9 on the iPads (assuming that nothing has been changed on the server and in the NSFs)?

Comment: Yes - we have discovered that is the case. The JQM problem occurs in Safari on iOS 9 & Chrome on Windows, but not Firefox or IE11 on Windows. Upgrading to the latest version of JQM fixes the issue - but also changes a lot of the UI styling. The exceptions in the logs are a different unrelated issue I think.

Answer (score 0):

What jumps out are these lines:

```
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext.serverProcessSignedResource(NotesContext.java:975)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext.setSignerSessionRights(NotesContext.java:946)
```

I don't know which application is causing the problem, but it looks it may be having a problem assigning signer rights. It may be worth checking for multiple signers of design elements.

Answer (score 0):

The `com.ibm.xsp.acl.NoAccessSignal` exception is thrown when an anonymous user tries to access a protected XPages resource. So this exception has nothing to do with the strange behaviour that you are experiencing.